# NullPointerException in AsyncTask OnPostExecute

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am getting `data=null` when executing the onPostExecute which is correct.Now I just want to show a dialog that there is no data available.But I am getting the `NullPointerException`.

```
public class GetPreviousChatNewThread extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

            ProgressDialog dialog;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;

            @Override
            protected  Void doInBackground(Void... void1) {
                data=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                data=HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats(sendHttpRequest(
                        "ReturnUserAdminChats",
                        "admin",
                        "You" ,
                        "a",
                        clientEmail,
                        UserAdminChatActivity.LastShowingChatDate));
                return null;
            }

            @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);


                if(!data.isEmpty())      // <-- error here
                {   
                    adapter.InsertValuesAtTop(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No more data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(dialog.isShowing())
                 dialog.dismiss();

             }

            @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UserAdminChatActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
             }

        }
```

Here's my Logcat which shows the complete log of the process:

```
07-23 12:22:55.976: I/finalAnswer(25159): ["a@hotmail.com","c@hotmail.com","b@hotmail.com"]
07-23 12:23:01.101: I/finalAnswer(25159): [{"username":"moji","chatText":"jingalala hu","chatDate":"4\\July\\2012"},{"username":"You","chatText":"bingalala hu","chatDate":"4\\July\\2012"},{"username":"moji","chatText":"jingalala hu","chatDate":"4\\July\\2012"}]
07-23 12:23:01.101: I/GoTo Json(25159): [{"username":"moji","chatText":"jingalala hu","chatDate":"4\\July\\2012"},{"username":"You","chatText":"bingalala hu","chatDate":"4\\July\\2012"},{"username":"moji","chatText":"jingalala hu","chatDate":"4\\July\\2012"}]
07-23 12:23:01.101: I/dateeeeeee(25159): 4\July\2012
07-23 12:23:01.101: I/dateeeeeee(25159): 4\July\2012
07-23 12:23:01.111: I/dateeeeeee(25159): 4\July\2012
07-23 12:23:01.161: I/finalAnswer(25159): new"[]"
07-23 12:23:02.603: I/finalAnswer(25159): []
07-23 12:23:02.603: I/GoTo Json(25159): []
07-23 12:23:02.613: D/AndroidRuntime(25159): Shutting down VM
07-23 12:23:02.613: W/dalvikvm(25159): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d578)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at com.app.ServerClient.UserAdminChatActivity$GetPreviousChatNewThread.onPostExecute(UserAdminChatActivity.java:197)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at com.app.ServerClient.UserAdminChatActivity$GetPreviousChatNewThread.onPostExecute(UserAdminChatActivity.java:1)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
07-23 12:23:02.623: E/AndroidRuntime(25159):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit:

Heres the code for HandleJson:

```
public class HandleJSON {

private static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> chat;
static final String Key_username="username_key";
static final String Key_email="email_key";
static final String Key_messageText="messageText_key";
static final String Key_messageDate="messageDate_key";
static final String Key_messageCounts="messageCount_key";
static boolean newObject;

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>  ParseJsonForLatestChats(String jsonData)
{
       try {

           if(HandleJSON.newObject)
           {
               chat=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
           }
           Log.i("jsonReturned",jsonData.toString());
           JSONArray jsonarr=new JSONArray(jsonData);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++)
            {   
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String,String>();

                hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_username, jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("username"));
                hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_email, jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("email"));
                hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_messageCounts, jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("count"));

                chat.add(hashMap);

            }

            return chat;
      }
      catch(JSONException e)
      {
          Log.e("JsonDek", e.getMessage());
          return null;
      }
}

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>  ParseJsonForUserAdminChats(String jsonData)
{

       chat=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

try {

         JSONArray jsonarr=new JSONArray(jsonData);
         Log.i("GoTo Json",jsonData);
            UserAdminChatActivity.LastShowingChatDate=jsonarr.getJSONObject(0).getString("chatDate");
            for(int i=jsonarr.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
            {   
                HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<String,String>();

                hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_username, jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("username"));
                hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_messageText, jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("chatText"));
                hashMap.put(HandleJSON.Key_messageDate, jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("chatDate"));
                Log.i("dateeeeeee",jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("chatDate"));

                chat.add(hashMap);

            }


            return chat;
      }
      catch(JSONException e)
      {
          return null;
      }
}


public static ArrayList<String> ReturnUsersEmail(String jsonData) throws JSONException
{
    JSONArray jsonarr=new JSONArray(jsonData);
    ArrayList<String> emails=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++)
    {
        emails.add(jsonarr.getString(i));
    }

    return emails;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using `AsyncTask` properly.
If you read the section called **AsyncTask's generic types** in [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you will learn how to use the generic types to pass data between `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`.
Here is what you need to do:

```
public class GetPreviousChatNewThread extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected  List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... void) {
            return HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats(sendHttpRequest(
                    "ReturnUserAdminChats",
                    "admin",
                    "You" ,
                    "a",
                    clientEmail,
                    UserAdminChatActivity.LastShowingChatDate));
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(null != result && !result.isEmpty()) { //checks not null or empty
                adapter.InsertValuesAtTop(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No more data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(dialog.isShowing())
             dialog.dismiss();

         }

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UserAdminChatActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
         }

    }
```

If you do get a `Toast`, then you know the data returned by `HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats(...)` is returning `null` or an empty `List`.

Comment: hey thnx for the reply.I tried the code but it's still giving the same error.

Comment: I seriously doubt it. There is **no way** you are recieving a NPE at the `if(null != result && !result.isEmpty())`. The most likely scenario here is that you are getting an NPE inside of `HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats`. Can you post that code? Maybe we can help you find the problem there.

Comment: @Mj1992 can you post the logs using my code? Including the Logs inside the `HandleJSON` class?

Comment: Also above the error that you originally posted looks like another error. Whats that one?

Comment: I've edited the logcat part of the question and inserted the complete log that occured during the complete process.It's from your code.

Comment: thnx for the help.the error was in the HandleJson.I returned the chat after the try catch block which helped me to identify if the list is null.

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a debugger. Either `doInBackground` doesn't get called (which is *very* unlikely), or your `ParseJSONForUserAdminChats` returns null. My bet is on the latter.

Comment: yeah it is returning null as i've mentioned in the question thats correct now I just want to show that there is no data to the user

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix for your exception would be to change the line to:

```
 if (null != data  &&  !data.isEmpty())
```

I think the reason `data` is `null` (instead of empty) there is because `HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats()` is returning `null`.  (Note that the `new` that you do immediately before that is not needed nor helpful, btw.)

Comment: yeah you are right it returns arraylist of hashmaps but since there is not data there so it is returning null

Comment: @Mj1992 It gives a null pointer exception on that same line?  If data really is `null`, that should not be the case.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Mj1992 Oh, I guess you should try one more thing (although I don't think this is related):  get rid of the `return null;` line from `doInBackground()`.

Comment: @Turix in his code he cannot remove the `return null;` as he will get a compilation error. Its there because he isn't using `AsyncTask` as intended... See my post. :)

Comment: @Salil_Pandit Yeah, saw it, and your code is definitely better than his.  But I still don't understand what the null check on `data` didn't at least avoid the exception.

Comment: @Turix I am thinking the NPE is in fact in his `HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats` code. Especially since he says running my code also threw an error... Which it can't. The only code we havent seen is the one running inside of that function.

Comment: @Turix it was giving exception on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am sure this is not your real code.
Anyway if you can do it run and get this exception, can't you handle it with a try catch?
Maybe you method "HandleJSON.ParseJsonForUserAdminChats" is nullifing the object and isEmpty only handles if list has no elements and dont handle if variable is null.

```
try {
  if(!data.isEmpty()) {
     //if data is not null and not empty will pass here
  }
} catch(NullPointerException e) {
  //If data == null it will pass here
}
```

Comment: So how can I handle null for a list can you please explain?

Comment: You can just check like Turix saied, or handle it by using like what I will post as an edit in mu post.

Answer (score 0):

if(!data.isEmpty())
It's not about the data! It's about the result. All return data are stored in result.